# Por qué hay el subjuntivo en la primera parte de una oracíon "A quienes haya sorprendido esto es que no estaban bien informados"

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

El título de un video de BBC Mundo: "*A quienes **haya sorprendido** esto es que no estaban bien informados*"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BDFWi95rm8

¿Por qué esta oración empieza con el subjuntivo? Aquí no hay ninguna palabra ("cuando", "tal vez") que a veces puede provocar el uso del subjuntivo.

Yo pensaba en la frase fija "una vez haya hecho" e intentaba encontrar de alguna forma la respuesta basándome en esto, pero sin haber podido llegar a una conclusión.

P.S. Como siempre, les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores  si hay algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Comment: Porque hay incertidumbre, no se sabe quien fue sorprendido ni si todos lo fueron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la oración:

- A quienes **haya** sorprendido esto es que no estaban bien informados.

el subjuntivo es correcto porque no se sabe si alguien fue efectivamente sorprendido o no (el subjuntivo expresa duda). Si tenemos la seguridad de que alguien fue sorprendido, entonces usamos el indicativo:

- A quienes **ha** sorprendido esto es que no estaban bien informados.

Más allá del modo verbal, debo decir que la oración presenta una redacción muy pobre y es sintácticamente imposible de analizar por ser de dudosa gramaticalidad, siendo tal vez una versión resumida de:

- A quienes haya sorprendido esto les digo que es porque no estaban bien informados.

Una mejor oración para expresar la idea sería:

- Si a alguien le ha sorprendido esto, es porque no estaba bien informado.

o

- Quienes hayan sido sorprendidos por esto sepan que es porque no estaban bien informados.

Comment: Tengo entendido. ¿Por qué en "Si a alguien le ha sorprendido esto, es porque no estaba bien informado" no se usa el subjuntivo?

Comment: En primer lugar, se dice: He entendido. "Tengo entendido" necesita un OD: tengo entendido que ... (solo NO funciona). En respuesta a tu pregunta, NUNCA se usa presente de subjuntivo después de "si".